# How to fetch a page's HTML code from www using C?

Tags: c, http, url, web

I just want to fetch a webpage(its HTML code,if its like www.example.com/example.html) into a text file using C. Is it possible using any library study or anything?
I am really getting lost into "maybe i should learn" PHP or python or something and then use command line invocation of these scripts using system() or exec(). Whats the best way to do so?

My Exact current need is to fetch `http://livechat.rediff.com/sports/score/score.txt`, which by chance happened to be a .txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [curl or libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/).  It will fetch a webpage for you and you can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: Means curl would work as external call, and libcurl is what i should use if I am thinking of "writing a code,built an executable and give it to my friends who don't have curl on their system". Am I getting it all right?

Comment: curl is freely available so your friends could download it, but yes libcurl is (I think) what you would use to integrate it with your c code.

Comment: Will take me ages to make them understand how to download and place it in proper directory.  Anyways Thnq :-) 
Wasted like 4 hours before getting here. When you don't know the solution, it feels like it must be exactly on the other end of the world from where you are.

Answer (score 3):

As Toby already mentioned, libcurl is probably your best bet.  Here is an actual program demonstrating how retrieve a webpage using the [libcurl-easy](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html) interface:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode curl_result;
    const char *site;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s site\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }   

    site = argv[1];

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, site);
        curl_result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(curl_result != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(curl_result));
        }   

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }   
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize curl\n");
        return 1;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

The program takes one argument, the name of the site to retrieve.  When compiled with `gcc curltest.c -lcurl -o curltest` and run as `curltest http://livechat.rediff.com/sports/score/score.txt`, outputs the following:

```
l1=England vs South Africa
l2=England
interval=1
message=England 16-2 (13)
tagline=J Trott(6) I Bell(4)* 
date=19 August, 2012
ver=19
```